Very slow reading of directory tree on secondary SSD
I have 2 SSDs:
$ df -h | grep sd
/dev/sda2       916G  130G  740G  15% /
/dev/sdb3       916G  346G  523G  40% /media/olddisk

Both disks were bought within the last 4 years, plugged into the SATA connectors on the motherboard, and formatted as ext4. sdb3 is my old disk, which used to be my only disk (and was sda2 then). When I added a second disk, I made the new disk my primary one, moved the old disk to the second connector, plugged the new disk to the first connector, and installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on it.
When I copy a large file from sdb3 to sda2, the speed is reasonable: about 2s for a 2GB file. However, when I copy a directory tree, the speed is horrendous: a directory tree consisting of about 400 files and totalling 2GB in size, takes about 3 minutes!
It seems the time is spent reading the directory tree from sdb3 rather than writing the directory tree to sda2. For example, the following command also takes about 3 minutes:
time tar cf /tmp/tmp1 /media/olddisk/home/klitos/Pictures/2005

On the other hand, when I read the exact same content from sda2, it takes only a few seconds:
time tar cf /tmp/tmp1 /home/klitos/Pictures/2005

What steps should I take to find out why it's taking so long to read the directory tree on my old disk, and to improve its performance?

After further investigation I found that the slow reads were caused by a number of files that were extremely slow to read, taking just under a second per megabyte. I then found various articles explaining that this is a common phenomenon with many SSDs: read speed degrades for old files. See, for example, https://www.reddit.com/r/unRAID/comments/10bi4sc/ssds_that_dont_slow_down_reading_old_files/
In my case, the disk with very slow reads is a SanDisk SDSSDH3. SanDisk is owned by Western Digital, which is one of the makes reported to exhibit this problem.
